# Merging columns using left join in SQL

Tags: sql

I am trying to merge columns from three different tables, the tables are as follows:

```
ID     Name      Location1  
1      John      Ams
2      Elvis     DH 
3      Stuart    NY
4      Tim       CAL
```

```
ID     Name      Location2    
1      John      ROT
2      Elvis     FT
```

```
ID     Name      Location3 
1      John      HOL
```

Desired output should be such that inner join is based on ID, a column is created named "Last location" that equals Table3.Location3 if filled in, otherwise Table2.Location2 if filled in, otherwise Table1.Location1. So desired output should be:

```
ID     Name      Last location
1      John      HOL
2      Elvis     FT
3      Stuart    NY
4      Tim       CAL
```

I am currently using a left join but I do not know how to override values, so I am getting all three columns:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID) LEFT JOIN Table 3 ON Table2.ID = Table3.ID;
```

Hence this gives:

```
ID     Name      Location1     Location2     Location3
1      John      Ams           ROT           HOL
2      Elvis     DH            FT
3      Stuart    NY
4      Tim       CAL
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to read some documentation about the function COALESCE, and next time please add info on which RDBMS you are using.(MySQL/MariaDB/MSSQL/Postgresql/.... )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your RDBMS

```
SELECT 
  Table1.ID, 
  COALESCE(Table3.Location3, Table2.Location2, Table1.Location1) AS LAST_LOCATION
FROM Table1 
LEFT JOIN Table2 
ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID
LEFT JOIN Table 3 
ON Table2.ID = Table3.ID;
```

Or

```
SELECT 
  Table1.ID, 
  NVL(Table3.Location3, NVL(Table2.Location2, Table1.Location1))
FROM Table1 
LEFT JOIN Table2 
ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID
LEFT JOIN Table 3 
ON Table2.ID = Table3.ID;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [COALESCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) : Evaluates the arguments in order and returns the current value of the first expression that initially doesn't evaluate to `NULL`. For example, `SELECT COALESCE(NULL, NULL, 'third_value', 'fourth_value');` returns the third value because the third value is the first value that isn't null.

Try like below.

```
SELECT Table1.ID, Table1.Name, COALESCE(Table3.Location3, Table2.Location2, Table1.Location1) AS [Last location]
FROM Table1 
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID
LEFT JOIN Table3 ON Table1.ID = Table3.ID;
```

---

Alternatively you can use `ISNULL` twice as below.

```
SELECT Table1.ID, Table1.Name, ISNULL(Table3.Location3, ISNULL(Table2.Location2, Table1.Location1)) AS [Last location]
FROM Table1 
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID
LEFT JOIN Table3 ON Table1.ID = Table3.ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

This way you don't lose any ID if an ID is not in one of the tables

```sql
SELECT
COALESCE(t3.ID, taux.ID) as ID
COALESCE(t3.Location2, taux.LastLocation) as LastLocation

FROM (SELECT
COALESCE(t2.ID, t1.ID) as ID,
COALESECE(t2.Location2, t1.Location1) as LastLocation
FROM Table1 t1
FULL JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.ID = t1.ID) taux
FULL JOIN  Table3 t3 ON t3.ID = taux.ID;
```

Comment: Who is loosing ID's?

Answer (score -1):

SELECT Table1.ID, Table1.Name, case when Table3.Location3 is not null then Table3.Location3 when Table2.Location2 is not null then Table2.Location2 else Table1.Location1 end AS Location1 FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID LEFT JOIN Table3 ON Table1.ID = Table3.ID;